# Nextcord Auto Nick System with Roles

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

following problem is

That I would like to change the nickname when you get a role, but unfortunately the following happens with my code:

```
async def update_nickname(member):
    leitung_role = nextcord.utils.get(member.guild.roles, name='Leitung')
    dev_role = nextcord.utils.get(member.guild.roles, name='Developer')

    if leitung_role in member.roles:
        new_nickname = f'Leitung | {member.user}'
    elif dev_role in member.roles:
        new_nickname = f'Dev | {member.user}'
    else:
        new_nickname = member.name

    if new_nickname != member.nick:
        try:
            await member.edit(nick=new_nickname)
        except nextcord.Forbidden:
            print(f"Could not change nickname for {member.name}")
```

it just doesn't come out what I want

since Discord has now released this new Discord Username update, you now have two names

`Username: jaymes Display name: James`

the following is output with my code:

```
Dev | jaymes (username)
```

but what should actually come out as a nickname:

```
Dev | James (Display Name)
```

Can someone help me with that?

Answer (score 0):

Simply use `member.display_name`. You can find the reference here: [nextcord.Member.display_name](https://docs.nextcord.dev/en/stable/api.html#nextcord.Member.display_name)

**Your new code:**

```py
async def update_nickname(member):
    leitung_role = nextcord.utils.get(member.guild.roles, name='Leitung')
    dev_role = nextcord.utils.get(member.guild.roles, name='Developer')

    if leitung_role in member.roles:
        new_nickname = f'Leitung | {member.display_name}' # Change to display_name
    elif dev_role in member.roles:
        new_nickname = f'Dev | {member.display_name}' # Change to display_name
    else:
        new_nickname = member.display_name # Change to display_name

    if new_nickname != member.nick:
        try:
            await member.edit(nick=new_nickname)
        except nextcord.Forbidden:
            print(f"Could not change nickname for {member.name}")
```

Comment: That doesn't work either

Comment: @Taycen Which name is displayed then?

Comment: As with nextcord.Member.name, nextcord.Member.display_name becomes Dev | jaymes and not Dev | James displayed

Comment: @Taycen You asked for the display name in your original question though. Is the display name `James` or `james` as well?

Comment: Otherwise, update your `nextcord` version as it was not supported in some versions ago: https://github.com/nextcord/nextcord/pull/1061

Comment: How do I get the new `nextcord` version? I'm not that into Github and can't get along with it, where do I have to go to get the new version or how do I install it?